# Angular - Dropdownlist onchange in FormArray to call a function

Tags: angular

I have a FormArray function in component.ts that generates controls. I don't know how to call the function in component.ts from component.html using dropdown onchange

I have written functions in component.ts, components.html

component.ts

```
addSubmenugroup(j) {
      console.log(j);
      const control = < FormArray > this.form.get('submenus')['controls'][j].get('submenugroups');
      control.push(this.initSubmenugroup());
  }

  getSubmenugroups(submenuform) {
      return submenuform.controls.submenugroups.controls;
  }

  initSubmenugroup() {
      return new FormGroup({
          submenuOption: new FormControl(''),
          submenuTake: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      });
  }
```

component.html

```
<select class="form-control select2" formControlName="submenuReplyType" type="text" style="width: 100%;" [(ngModel)]="optionsubValue">
    <option value="predefinedsub">Pre-Defined</option>
    <option value="opentypesub">OpenType</option>

</select>

<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngIf="optionsubValue == 'opentypesub'">
    <label>Take him to Menu</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="type" type="text">
        <option value="menu1">Menu 1</option>
        <option value="menu2">Menu 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Onchange, if value is OpenType

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngIf="optionsubValue == 'opentypesub'">
    <label>Take him to Menu</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="type" type="text">
        <option value="menu1">Menu 1</option>
        <option value="menu2">Menu 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

should be visible, else if value is Pre-Defined then the function addSubmenu should be called from component.html.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to call method on dropdown change event. You can call your method on the change event of Select tag as shown below:

```
   Component.html
  <select (change)="callyourfunction($event.target.value)" class="form-control" 
  formControlName="type" type="text">
  <option value="menu1">Menu 1</option>
  <option value="menu2">Menu 2</option>
  </select> 

component.ts
   callyourfunction(val: any) {
    if (val == "Menu1")
        {
     }
    else if(val == "Menu2"){

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding" *ngIf="optionsubValue == 'opentypesub'">
  <label>Take him to Menu</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="type" type="text">
      <option *ngFor="let each of [yourListResponse];let i=index" value="menu1">{{each.menu1}}</option>
    </select>                                         
</div>
```

**[yourListResponse] is an array you get from your backend or wherever
    {{each.menu1}} is one of the response that contains lists**

Comment: do not include the square bracket

Comment: What is $event.target.value in the function